# MySQL query for matches

Tags: mysql

I'm building a search query that needs to return a list of people. Depending on the amount of fields that match the user gets a higher "match" rating. Now I was wondering if in the returned array from the query, the more fields match the higher they will be in the array? If not what might be a good solution?

Comment: You should probably use something like Solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: Also worth checking out: [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).